# libnpjp2.so Does Not Exist

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, java

I have successfully installed the official Oracle Java JDK on my computer running Debian 8.7.0.  However, I am unable to install the Java plugin for FireFox.  To install the plugin, I must create a link to the `libnpjp2.so` file in the `java/lib/amd64` directory.  However, that file does not exist.  Any link pointed to it is declared broken.  The directory tree contains only the following files

```
amd64/
├── jli
│   └── libjli.so
└── libjawt.so
```

I have downloaded and reinstalled the tarball from Oracle's web site multiple times, but the file was never present.

All searches on the subject only turned up information about people with the OpenJDK and I can find no other occurrences of the problem.

Is there any way to install the plugin without the file?  Is it possible to create a new link to whatever the file was pointing to?  I have installed IcedTea in the mean time, but I would like everything to be the same version of Java.

---

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is relative to the JRE, so if you're installing JDK, it seems like the file is actually located in:

*java/jre/lib/amd64/*

instead of just:

*java/lib/amd64/*

because JRE is a part of JDK.

This worked for me (I'm using openSUSE leap 42.2 and Java 1.8.0_121), and for some Ubuntu user in 2013 (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196114).

If this doesn't work, try looking for this file in *java/* directory, it's most likely somewhere in there.